# CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost giving ConnectTimeoutException

Tags: php, android, timeout

### I have some problems with the timeout when requesting my login.php

> 02-10 20:23:26.361: V/(1084): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.2.2:8082 timed out

- I'm very similar to this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435535/android-and-php-login-authentication) but additionally i add some snippets from my code now.

### LoginActivity.java

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8082/login/login.php",postParameters);
```

In the *CustomHttpClient.java* I get the timeout after the execute at the end.

```
HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
request.setEntity(formEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The timeout comes after 5 seconds cause I used

```
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 5 * 1000; 
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }
```

in the executeHttpPost method

### My login.php looks like this.

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$pws = 'test';

try {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=toDoList", $username, $pws);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE name = '$name'");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row)
        {
            echo ($pw == $row['password'] ? '1' : '0');
        }

    }
        catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: is this page accessible from the device's browser?

Comment: how can i test this? the XAMPP Server runs on my localhost, but if its available also from the emulator I really don't know. Some workarounds to test it?

Comment: btw guys i fixed it by myself, just let the port 8082 away and it works

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the URL your are pointing to is actually available by accessing from a regular browser on your computer.
2. If 1) succeeds, make sure that you can access it from the browser in the emulator. If it doesn't, disable the computer and try again with only wireless enabled.

Comment: Yes but the question ist how i check the availability on my emulator. A little workaround or tutorial for this would be awesome. I'm not able to check it with the Android browser btw.

Comment: Open the browser in your emulator, and point it to http://10.0.2.2:8082/login/login.php.